# vue3 object deep reactivity works fine but getting error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

I am using composition api fetching data with firestore, the render view works fine but the console got some errors and the vue-router couldn't work correctly, maybe is the reason of vue deep reactivity.
Here is my setup function.

```
setup() {
const route = useRoute();
const state = reactive({});
const getData = async () => {
  const snapshot = await articlesCollection
    .doc(auth.currentUser.uid + "/userArticles/" + route.params.aID)
    .get();
  state.article = snapshot.data();
  console.log(state.article);
};
getData();
return {
  state,
};
```

and the template goes like this

```
<span class="text-lg font-semibold ml-2">
   {{ state.article.author.name }}
</span>
```

Here is the error I got and the console goes with :
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of undefined

```
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug.
```

why isn't it reactive?
I hope someone can help me out here.
Much appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the initial value of `state` is `{}`
when it renders your `state.article.author.name`, it will throw an error.
to fix it, you can add a judgement in your tempalte

```
<span class="text-lg font-semibold ml-2">
   {{ state.article && state.article.author.name }}
</span>
```